# An array of object with specific type using generics with typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

I want to have an array of objects of the following type (arbitrary length):

```
[
  {p1: T,  p2: T}, 
  {p1: T2, p2: T2}
  ...
]
```

For a single object, this works as I want it to:

```
type O<T> = {
  p1: T;
  p2: T;
};


const f = <T,>(a: O<T>) => { 
  console.log(a) 
}

f({ p1: 1, p2: 2 }); // makes sure p1 and p2 has the same type
```

I want to pass to the function `f` an array of objects, and I want each object individually to have the same type constraint.

I tried:

```
O<T> = {
  p1: T;
  p2: T;
}

const f = <T,>(a: O<T>[]) => { 
  console.log(a) 
}

f([
  { p1: 1, p2: 2 },
  { p1: '3', p2: '4' }, // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
]);
```

I also tried:

```
type O<T> = {
  p1: T;
  p2: T;
};

type A<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: O<T[P]>;
};

const f = <T,>(a: A<T>) => { 
  console.log(a) 
}

f([
  { p1: 1, p2: 2 },
  { p1: 3, p2: '4' }, // allows but I don't want it to be allowed p1 != p2 unfortunatly T resolvs to string | number
]);
```

I want `O<T>` to be applied for each object in the array individually.
I tried so many things, that at this point I'm not sure if it is possible to achieve this with typescript.

I want this to work for any custom type not only `number | string`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your `O` type expects `p1` and `p2` but then you use `p3` and `p4`. Do you want to make each object with increased by 1 suffix ?

Comment: I never use p3 or p4. Each object in the array has p1 and p2 properties. The type differs for each object inside the array. Ex: [{p1: string, p2: string}, {p1: number; p2: number}...].

Comment: sorry,  my bad, overlooked

Comment: Please let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/mM4adN) works for you

Comment: This is amazing, exactly what I was looking for!! I struggled so much finding a solution for this, I thought it was actually not possible... This works perfectly, many thanks! If you want you can copy that into an answer so others can see the solution too, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, we need to infer each element from the list and check whether `p1` and `p2` have same types.

To infer each element from list we need to use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types). Apart from that , we need to iterate through each element an check `p1` and `p2`.

See this:

```js
type BothEqual<T extends Base<any>> =
    T['p1'] extends T['p2']
    ? (T['p2'] extends T['p1']
        ? T
        : never)
    : never

type Validation<
    Arr extends Array<unknown>,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = []
    > =
    Arr extends []
    ? []
    : (Arr extends [infer H extends Base<any>]
        ? [...Result, BothEqual<H>]
        : (Arr extends [infer Head extends Base<any>, ...infer Tail]
            ? Validation<[...Tail], [...Result, BothEqual<Head>]>
            : Readonly<Result>)
    )
```

`BothEqual` just checks whether `p1` and `p2` have same type.

`Validation` - iterates through eack element in the list and calls `BothEqual` on it.
Hence, if elem is valid it returns this element otherwise it returns `never`:

```js
interface Base<T> {
    p1: T,
    p2: T
};


type BothEqual<T extends Base<any>> =
    T['p1'] extends T['p2']
    ? (T['p2'] extends T['p1']
        ? T
        : never)
    : never


type Validation<
    Arr extends Array<unknown>,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = []
    > =
    /**
     * If Arr is empty tuple, return empty result
     */
    Arr extends []
    ? []
    /**
     * If Arr is a tuple with one element, stop recursion.
     * See TS 4.7 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables docs
     * for [infer H extends Base<any>] syntax
     * 
     */
    : (Arr extends [infer H extends Base<any>]
        ? [...Result, BothEqual<H>]
        /**
         * If Arr has more than one element - call it recursively
         */
        : (Arr extends [infer Head extends Base<any>, ...infer Tail]
            ? Validation<[...Tail], [...Result, BothEqual<Head>]>
            : Readonly<Result>)
    )


function f<T, List extends Base<T>[]>(a: [...List] & Validation<[...List]>) {
    console.log(a)
}

f([
    { p1: 1, p2: 2 },
    { p1: 3, p2: '42' } // error
]);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NlEJrm)
As you might have noticed, second element in provided argument is highlighted.
Also, you can prioritize `p1` over `p2`. It mean that `p1` is the source of true. Then, if `p2` is invalid only `p2` will be highlighted.
Try this:

```js
type BothEqual<T extends Base<any>> =
    T['p2'] extends T['p1']
    ? T
    : Omit<T, 'p2'> & { p2: never }
```

You can simplify `Validation` type:

```js
type Validation<
    Arr extends Array<unknown>,
    > =
    {
        [Elem in keyof Arr]: Arr[Elem] extends Base<any> ? BothEqual<Arr[Elem]> : never
    }
```

But then all elements in the array will be highlighted which might be hard to understand what went wrong.

If you are interested in TS function argument validation and tuple iteration you can check these articles from my blog:

- [Working with tuples](https://catchts.com/tuples)
- [Validations](https://catchts.com/validators)
- [type negations](https://catchts.com/type-negation)

Answer (score 0):

I think you had it at the outset ;-)

```
type O<T1, T2> = [ { p1: T1, p2: T1 }, { p3: T2, p4: T2 } ]

function f<T1,T2>(a: O<T1, T2>) { 
  console.log(a) 
}

f([
  { p1: 1, p2: 2 },
  { p3: '3', p4: '4' }
]);

f<number, string>([
  { p1: 1, p2: 2 },
  { p3: '3', p4: '4' }
]);

f<number, string>([
  { p1: 1, p2: 2 },
  { p3: 3, p4: '4' }
  //^^ Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
]);
```

Part of the issue with correctly warning on `{p3: 3, p4: '4'}` without an explicit type, the generic `f` is inferring the type based on the input argument.  It's telling you that the second object cannot have mismatched types, but they could be the same as the first objects type (`T1` and `T2` could legitimately be the same type).

You could make the generic conditional, so that `T2` cannot extend `T1` but that might be restrictive with objects without knowing the shape of them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works with an array of lengths two. What if want to array with an arbitrary number of elements not only two? Each object has p1 and p2 properties.

Comment: Not what you asked for first time around!

Comment: You're right. I updated the answer. Sorry, that was indeed confusing.